# toggle applied on my all class

Tags: jquery, toggle

my problem is all click funcion apply on for all class. it normal i understand because i used same class. but i don't know how to apple that for now. i don't want to use id caz it will be dynamic . so i want when i click details/next step. each will effect only for that box alone.

example like

```
http://www.snoblife.com/snob-university/ >> PICK A CLASS! section
```

bellow is my code js code for my html.

```
$( ".icon-plus" ).click(function() {
$( ".traningcontent" ).slideToggle( "slow" );

});


$( ".next-step" ).click(function() {
$( ".traningcontent" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
$( ".2ndstep" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/Sac5m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the element base on the current clicked element. To do so, you can use `this` key inside you function.

After that, you can navigate in the tree with `.find` and `.closest` just like that :

```
$( ".icon-plus" ).click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.traningbox');
    $container.find( ".traningcontent" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});


$( ".next-step" ).click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.traningbox');
    $container.find( ".traningcontent" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
    $container.find( ".2ndstep" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Sac5m/1/

Comment: wow. it work nice. thanks if more thing if you never mind. i want next-step button will be disable until fill the form. after fill the all inputs then next-step will enable/clickable.

Comment: @pagol i'm giving you a freebie but that's the only one! I will not answer any question unrelated to this answer. http://jsfiddle.net/Sac5m/3/

Comment: After reading my comment, I think i'm a little harsh, but what I meant is that I will not do all the work for you! But I'm a nice guy :)

Comment: no no i don't mean work for me man :) i am trying myself. u already help me alot :) thanks again for that.

Comment: again Double Thanks :) save my much time.

Answer (score 1):

you have to get cuurent clicked element reference and slideToggle its respective elements:

```
$( ".icon-plus" ).click(function() {
$(this).closest(".traningbox").find( ".traningcontent" ).slideToggle( "slow" );

});


$( ".next-step" ).click(function() {
$(this).closest(".traningbox").find( ".traningcontent" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
$(this).closest(".traningbox").find( ".2ndstep" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sac5m/2/)

### Explanation:

`$(this)` will give you current clicked element reference, then using `closest()` we get its parent element with class trainingbox `$(this).closest(".traningbox")` and then inside trainingbox we find `traningcontent` using `find( ".traningcontent" )` and then toggle it:

```
$(this).closest(".traningbox").find( ".traningcontent" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
```

Comment: thank u so much. it also work nicely. and your explain nicely which is easy for me understand. stackoverflow have no option for two correction answer. if have then i will make your one also correction answer.

Comment: if you never mind. i want next-step button will be disable until fill the form. after fill the all inputs then next-step will enable/clickable.